# Cannot solve indefinite integral

Tags: integration, analysis, indefinite-integrals

can You help me with this indefinite integral

$$\int \dfrac{2^{x + 1} + 5^x}{10^x} dx$$

What to use. direct integration or substitute of variables
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\int \dfrac{2^{x + 1} + 5^x}{10^x} dx=\int 2 \times5^{-x}+2^{-x} dx$$

$$=2\int e^{-\ln(5)x} dx+\int e^{-\ln(2)x} dx=-2\frac{5^{-x}}{\ln(5)}-\frac{2^{-x}}{\ln(2)}+C$$

Comment: Yea, no problem lol

Comment: $\int \dfrac{2^{x + 1} + 5^x}{10^x} dx=\int \frac{1}{2}5^{-x}+2^{-x} dx$ is wrong. The $\frac{1}{2}5^{-x}$ should be $2*5^{-x}$

Comment: @Kuai Thanks, fixed it